# SyntaxError: Reserved word "function"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, hubot

I'm trying to code a script for Github's Hubot that uses TooTallNate's Node-Spotify-Web to play music through spotify, and I'm somewhat new to CoffeeScript (What Hubot scripts are written in). I wrote out the first command "Play" here:

http://pastebin.com/Pp6mqucm

```
lame = require('lame')
Speaker = require('speaker')
Spotify = require('spotify-web')

username = "INSERTUSERNAMEHERE"
password = "INSERTPASSWORDHERE"

robot.respond /play (.*)/i, (message) ->
  uri = message.match[1]
  Spotify.login(username, password, function (err, spotify)) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Playing: %s - %s', track.artist[0].name, track.name)
}
  spotify.get(uri, function(err, track){
        if err throw err;
        message.send("Playing:" + track.artist[0].name, track.name)
        })
```

Upon running bin/hubot I got the Error "Syntax Error, Reserved word "function" so I said, ok and changed 'function' to '->' as recommend in another StackOverflow question. Making it so it appeared as:

http://pastebin.com/dEw0VrH5

But still get the error

ERROR Unable to load /home/xbmc/cbot/lisa/scripts/spotify: SyntaxError: reserved word "function"

Is it because of the dependencies? I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Are you using CoffeeScript, as your question says, or JavaScript, as you put in the tags?

Comment: This doesn't look right `spotify.get(uri, ->(err, track){`. Also all you need to put formatted code in SO (or anywhere online) is convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: CoffeeScript, I apologize I completely forgot to add a tag for it.

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not in an external code-hosting service.

Comment: The code in the pastebins is incorrect; a mix of JS and Coffeescript. The question as-is qualifies as "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem".

Comment: @elclanrs: `->(err, track) { ... } ` looks like a Ruby "stabby" lambda, roughly the same as `function(err, track) { ... }` (JavaScript), or `(err, track) -> ...` (CoffeeScript), or `lambda { |err, track| ... }` (also Ruby).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the very first sections of the [coffee script documentation is how to declare functions](http://coffeescript.org/#literals). You don't just change the word `function` to `->`.  It's not that simple.  In Javascript functions are `function(args) { body }`, but in Coffee Script it's `(args) -> body`

But for brevity, when you have this:

```
Spotify.login(username, password, function (err, spotify)) {
```

That's not going to work CoffeeScript, because that's not the syntax for declaring functions.  You want:

```
Spotify.login username, password, (err, spotify) ->
  # function body
```

And the same here:

```
spotify.get(uri, function(err, track){
```

Which should be:

```
spotify.get uri, (err, track) ->
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript's function syntax is

```
(arguments...) ->
    body
```

and not

```
-> (arguments...) {
    body
}
```

You have the correct syntax too:

```
robot.respond /play (.*)/i, (message) ->
    uri = message.match[1]
    ....
```

Did you copy-paste a snippet from somewhere?

Comment: Some what, I've been attempting to write a script for hubot to control XBMC for most of the day so I understood some things, and then I was trying to follow the example from [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-spotify-web/blob/master/example/play.js) while trying to also make sure it works for hubot

Comment: Your reference is in JavaScript. You were writing CoffeeScript. It's like picking words for your English class composition from German edition of Faust. :)